# Dogs in islam is haram

Tags: sharia, dogs

Not all dogs are eligible for hunting, protecting crops etc. , my question is what are the purpose of these dogs if we can't have them around?

Comment: You might as well ask what the purpose is of mosquitoes if we can't use them for hunting or protecting crops; the world's full of animals which we can't use like that, why single out dogs here?

Answer (score 1):

Let me clarify a few myths and make a few points:

1. It is NOT haraam to own a dog, though it is not hygienic to keep a dog in the house.
2. It is NOT haraam to touch a dog or any other animal. If the saliva of a dog touches you or any part of your clothing, then it is required of you to wash the body part touched and the item of clothing touched by the dog’s mouth or snout.
3. It is incumbent upon all Muslims who own animals, whether for farming or work purposes or as pets, to provide adequate shelter, food, water, and, when needed, veterinary care for their animals. Arrangements must be made, if one is going to be away from home, to have one’s animals taken care of as well.
4. It is haraam to keep a dog or any other animal on a short lead for long periods without food, water, and shelter. Dogs need exercise and are social creatures who form organized “family” structures in nature. Dog owners therefore need to spend time daily with their dogs.
5. It is cruel, and therefore haraam, to keep any animal in a cage so small that it cannot behave in a natural way.
6. Fireworks cause untold suffering to most domestic animals because of their acute sense of hearing.
7. It is haraam to participate in any blood “sport,” like dog fighting and trophy hunting.

No animal has been cursed in any way. Animals are referred to in many instances in the Qu’ran. In Surah Kahf, mention is made of the companions of the Cave and their dog. (S18: 18-22)

We would love for Allah to bestow His mercy upon us, so let’s show mercy and compassion to all His creation. This will also give non-Muslims a true reflection of Islam, aiding da’wah.

Comment: Bit OT, but can the somewhat negative view on dogs, pigs and shrimps (in the Old Testament), have something to do with the fact that these animals could scavenge on human corpses (eg. after a battle or a boatwreck)?

Answer (score -2):

Slightly aside, but when you go out you are mindful of not stepping in animal filth such as dog / cat faeces or urine. A dog isn't careful. How can you be so sure when it enters your home it hasn't stepped in that or rolled around in the grass in the park in that? Further dogs don't wipe or wash after their toilet nor wear underpants. You wouldn't sit on your sofa or car seat if you didn't wipe or wash and didn't wear underpants or trousers? How can a dog then be allowed to sit on the sofa or go in your bed (yuk)? How can it then be hygienic to have a dog in the house? Same goes for a cat etc. Pet owners have overlooked these aspects completely in my humble opinion.

Comment: Welcome to Islam SE. Answers should be elaborate and focused on addressing the question. Claims should be supported by evidence. Please visit our [tour] in the [help], and refer to [answer].

Comment: Dogs can be and are  trained to poop outside the house, they are very intelligent animals. `Further dogs don't wipe or wash after their toilet nor wear underpants. `, I hope you are kidding